# Sync birthdays between iCal and Android

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts, htc-desire, macos

I have an HTC Desire and a Mac (10.6, if that matters) and I sync them via Google Contacts.

Many of my contacts in Apple's Address Book.app have a birthday set, but it does not transfer to Google Contacts and thus not to my Android Contacts.

If I create a new contact on Google Mail/Contacts and set a birthday, it is immediately synced to my Android phone, complete with birthday, but in Address Book.app the birthday is missing.

**How can I get my birthdays in sync?**

If a proper sync is *not possible,* it would be nice to have at least a calendar that is synced, but I don't know how to add the calendar that Address Book.app can generate automatically to my Google account to sync.

I have seen [icalbirthdays](http://code.google.com/p/icalbirthdays/) but I don't think it can help me. I would like to avoid kludges like creating a calender from Address Book in iCal, publishing that to a third server and subscribing in Google Calendar...)

Comment: That's a tricky one. You say you sync Address Book with Google Contacts. How are you doing that? The setting in Address Book itself?

Comment: You might also want to consider asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com as this is also a Mac related question

Comment: @Al: Yes, I use the sync provided in Address Book: Accounts, "Synchronize with Google". @Bryan: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I am admittedly not an Apple guy, but it looks like you might need a third-party solution.

According to some comments I found [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/05/22/address-book-vs-google-contacts/), non-support of birthdays is a known thorn. To get around it, the commenter used [Spanning Sync](http://spanningsync.com/) but also mentioned [SyncMan](http://wateree.net/syncman/).

**Spanning Sync** offers a 15-day trial, after which it costs $25 for a one-year subscription or a $65 one-time purchase. The commenter referenced above did mention that he chose this because birthdays were not being sync'd.

**SyncMan** offers a 30-day trial, after which you can purchase it for $14.99. On the support page it specifically mentions birthdays as one of the things it syncs that the native Google sync in Address Book doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used Missing Sync, it's quite a good app for Mac

http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html